# 为了学钢琴调律，陈燕…… why is the answer 手经常会受伤?

Tags: meaning

This a cropped exercise from the HSK6 Standard Course workbook (chapter 3, page 25; [photo of original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLZvx.jpg); OCR by Yandex):

> 陈燕自小对音乐感兴趣，学过很多乐器。自打学调琴开始，她每天总是十三四个小时泡在钢琴边，仔细摸，用心记。学调律还必须会修琴，一个盲人手拿
> 睡子钉钉子、用创子创木头，受伤总是难免的。那段时间，她手上就没有一块好肉。
>
> 四年学习，陈燕掌握了最先进的钢琴调律技术，但……
>
> 35. 为了学钢琴调律，陈燕:
>     A 先学会了修琴
>     B 整整学了 13 年
>     C **手经常会受伤**
>     D 渐渐喜欢上了音乐

The given answer is C, and no further details are given.

I chose A because it says

> 学调律还必须会修琴

and because I thought 为了 should indicate something done intentionally to achieve a goal, and not merely a byproduct, like in this case 陈燕 repeatedly hurting her hands.  If she was able to choose not to hurt her hands, she would have.  I'm not sure where I went wrong here.

**Question**: 为了学钢琴调律，陈燕…… why is the answer 手经常会受伤?

Answer (score 2):

> 学调律还必须会修琴

It only says 调律 (tune piano) and 修琴(repair piano) have to be learned at the same time. You can't tune a piano if you don't know how to fix it; you can't fix a piano if you don't know how to tune it. All piano tuners are also piano repairers and vice versa

Similar to reading and writing have to be learned at the same time to advance either

The article compares her learning of 修琴 (repair piano) to 一个盲人手拿錘子钉钉子 (A blind man drives a nail with a hammer) And the result is the same -- 受伤总是难免的 (Injuries are always inevitable). To learn piano repairing, she needs to use her hands and metal tools extensively, and getting her hands hurt was unavoidable before she became skilled with the tools -- The answer 手经常会受伤 shows how hard she studied

Comment: According to the original article, Chen Yan was born blind. I think here "一个盲人" refers to Chen Yan.

Answer (score 0):

Let's review the question:

- 四年学习，陈燕掌握了最先进的钢琴调律技术，**但**……

Here, the word "**但/but (similar to except - 除了[上述]之外**)" indicates the tone has turned, and a negative effect from learning the piano and mastering piano tuning is anticipated.

Now let's check the sentences below:

- A. Through 4 years of learning, she has mastered the most advanced techniques for piano tuning, but "first learned how to repair the piano".
- C. Through 4 years of learning, she has mastered the most advanced techniques for piano tuning, but "often injured her hands (during the activities)".

Now, your choice, A or C? :)

Answer (score 0):

Why the answer is C - 手**经常**会受伤? The article said that "一个盲人手拿睡(锤)子钉钉子、用创(刨)子创(刨)木头，受伤总是难免的。那段时间，她手上就没有一块好肉。" You could argue that the phrase "总是难免的" means "not avoidable", not necessarily mean "经常 (often)". But the next sentence "那段时间，就没有" does tell you "经常 (often)"。

Why the answer is not A - **先**学会了修琴? If there is not the word "先 (beforehand)", then I think it can be the answer. "为了学钢琴调律，陈燕学会了修琴" is said in the article that "学调律还必须会修琴". But it is not necessarily in a timely order.